# File ended while scanning use of \next with comment package

Tags: comments

When using the `comment` package, one can get a very strange error

```
Runaway argument?
! File ended while scanning use of \next.
```

when compiling a file that excludes some comments

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{comment}
\excludecomment{enonce}

\begin{document}
 \begin{enonce}
  some text
 \end{enonce}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is clearly stated in the package manual:

> **The opening and closing commands should appear on a line of their own. No starting spaces, nothing after it.**

[image]

Comment: Oh you are right ! I had been searching for ages in this -- but it was late. I will amend the Q/A ; should I remove it entirely ? Maybe it could still be useful to other as a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

One cause of this error that I found was embedding a \begin{comment} and \end{comment} within conditional braces. Once I removed the comment commands, the error disappeared.

Comment: Well, but how does it solve the issue here? OP wants to use `comment`, you removed it ...